# Zoom In Problem!

Tags: html, css

I Have a problem with the zoom in on my site, it happens on both IE and Firefox. When I try to zoom in, the X-axis scroller appears at the bottom but the footer area (#content) doesn't show up across the screen when you scroll side ways.
Here is the link to the site: http://portfolio.htp.bcit.ca/akhodabandeh/portfolio_new_latest/

Thanks in advance

Comment: The actual problem is not with you footer, but with your banner. You assigned a fixed size here (1000px) which in zoom causes header menu overflow 100% width of pages. One solution would be to make banner with 100% dimension instead of absolute pixels (you might need to rewrite dimensions of inside elements for banner as well). Same for #btm_edge

Comment: @vlad, you should probably post your comment as an answer...

Comment: @justin - oh, ok :) wanted to wait for Nino's feedback, but your are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is not with you footer, but with your banner. You assigned a fixed size here (1000px) which in zoom causes header menu overflow 100% width of pages. One solution would be to make banner with 100% dimension instead of absolute pixels (you might need to rewrite dimensions of inside elements for banner as well). Same for #btm_edge

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, I'm just getting used to this site sorry about not leaving comments.